# A-star (A*) with "correct" heuristic function and without negative edges

Tags: graph, a-star, heuristics, state-space

In A* heuristic there is a step that **updates value of the node if better route to this node was found**. But what if we had **no negative edges** and **correct heuristic** function (**goal-aware, safe and consistent**). Is it true that updating will no longer be necessary because we always get to that state first by the shortest path?

**Considering the euclidean distance heuristic, it seems to me that it works but I am unable to generalize it in my thoughts as why it should. If not, can anyone provide me with a counter example or in other case confirm my initial though?**

*Context: I am solving a task with heuristic function which I don't really understand and I don't need to (pseudo-code is provided), but I am guaranteed it is (goal-aware, safe and consistent). The state space is huge so I am unable to build the graph so I am looking for a way how to completely omit remembering the graph and just keep a hash map so I know if I visited particular state before, therefore avoid the cycles.*

Answer (score 0):

So I have tested my hypothesis on various instances and it seems that even if the heuristic is (goal-aware, safe and consistent) and the "graph" is without negative edges, the first entry into the state might not be on the shortest possible path. (Some instances seemed to give proper result only if revisiting and updating the states as well as pushing them back into the openSet held by A* was supported.)

I wasn't able to isolate why, but when debugging, some states were visited multiple times and over the shorter path. My guess is that maybe it can happen when we go towards goal but add a neighbor in the graph which is in the direction away from the goal. Therefore being on the longer path that it can possibly be if we would move on the most optimized path from the start towards this node in the direction of the goal.